# How to instantiate object programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want instantiate some label in design from code. I don't want to make 50 label for each textBox. Just like unity I want to instantiate some object multiple times in design. How can I do it in visual studio in c#.

Comment: Is it a web app or desktop?

Comment: Make a Prefab for the label

Comment: [Instantiate tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/instantiate?language=en) **+** [How to create UI objects from scripts](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UICreateFromScripting.html)

Comment: @Immersive I somehow get the feeling that the `unity3d` tag shouldn't even be here as OP seems to refer to something completely different and mentioned Unity just as an example for the expected behavior

Comment: @Hellium see comment above

Comment: You might be right. I flagged the question for unclarity.

Answer (score 1):

You must create a label object dynamically for example :

```
int n = 4; // label counts

private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Label[] labels = new Label[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {        

        labels[i] = new Label();
        // Here you can modify the value of the label which is at labels[i]
    }

    // add labels to Controls container
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
    }
```